# How to create Azure VM with Public IP address through REST API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, cloud, virtual-machine

how to I create a Azure VM with a public IP address using requests through there API. This is the current request body but I dont know what I need to add to have the VM have an public IP address  - Thanks

```
{
  "location": "ukwest",
  "properties": {
    "hardwareProfile": {
      "vmSize": "Standard_B1s"
    },
    "storageProfile": {
      "imageReference": {
        "id": "/subscriptions/28f23ba2-c344-448c-808b-e45a97a29764/resourceGroups/main/providers/Microsoft.Compute/images/ukproxy"
      },
      "osDisk": {
        "caching": "ReadWrite",
        "managedDisk": {
          "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "name": "myVMosdisk",
        "createOption": "FromImage"
      }
    },
    "osProfile": {
      "adminUsername": "user",
      "computerName": "user",
      "adminPassword": "password!"
    },
    "networkProfile": {
      "networkInterfaces": [
        {
          "id": "/subscriptions/28f23ba2-c344-448c-808b-e45a97a29764/resourceGroups/main/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/nic",
          "properties": {
            "primary": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "name": "VM"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The public IP just associate to the network interface. So you do not need to worry about the public IP when you create the VM. All the thing you have to do is create the public IP and associate it to your interface which belongs to the VM.

For example, the request body when you create the network interface will like this:

```
{
  "name": "test-nic",
  "id": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/test-nic",
  "location": "eastus",
  "properties": {
    "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
    "ipConfigurations": [
      {
        "name": "ipconfig1",
        "id": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/test-nic/ipConfigurations/ipconfig1",
        "properties": {
          "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
          "privateIPAddress": "172.20.2.4",
          "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
          "publicIPAddress": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/test-ip"
          },
          "subnet": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/subid/resourceGroups/rg1/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/rg1-vnet/subnets/default"
          },
          "primary": true,
          "privateIPAddressVersion": "IPv4"
        }
      }
    ],
    "dnsSettings": {
      "dnsServers": [],
      "appliedDnsServers": []
    },
    "enableAcceleratedNetworking": true,
    "enableIPForwarding": false
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces"
}
```